# Concat two dataframes wit common columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with same columns. Only one column has different values. I want to concatenate the two without duplication.

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['K0', 'K1', 'K2'],'cat': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2'],'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2']})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['K0', 'K1', 'K2'],'cat': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2'],'B': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2']})

df1
Out[630]: 
  key cat   B
0  K0  C0  A0
1  K1  C1  A1
2  K2  C2  A2
df2
Out[631]: 
  key cat   B
0  K0  C0  B0
1  K1  C1  B1
2  K2  C2  B2
```

I tried:

```py
result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
result
Out[633]: 
  key cat   B key cat   B
0  K0  C0  A0  K0  C0  B0
1  K1  C1  A1  K1  C1  B1
2  K2  C2  A2  K2  C2  B2
```

The desired output:

```
  key cat   B_df1  B_df2
0  K0  C0    A0     B0
1  K1  C1    A1     B1
2  K2  C2    A2     B2
```

NOTE: I could drop duplicates afterwards and rename columns but that doesn't seem efficient

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pd.merge` will do the job

```
pd.merge(df1,df2, on=['key','cat'])
```

**Output**

```
  key cat   B_x   B_y
0  K0  C0    A0    B0
1  K1  C1    A1    B1
2  K2  C2    A2    B2
```

Comment: works but how about the names `B_x` & `B_y`, can I customize them?

Comment: @iamklaus kindly add suffixes=('_df1','_df2')